# Unsure why does Bubble sort code have a segmentation fault

Tags: c

Hi I'm using gdb to debug my bubble sort code but I don't get why it keeps breaking at `if(a[j] < a[j-1]`

here is my bubble sort function

```
void sort(int a[], int n) {
    int i, j, nswaps, tmp;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       nswaps = 0;
       for(j = 0; j > i; j++) {
           if(a[j] < a[j-1]) {
               tmp = a[j];
               a[j] = a[j-1];
               a[j-1] = tmp;
               nswaps++;
            }
       }
       if(nswaps == 0) break;
    }
}
```

Please do help me thanks!!

updated code: still has a segmentation fault

```
void sort(int a[], int n) {
int i, j, nswaps;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    nswaps = 0;
    for (j = 1; j > i; j++) {
        if (a[j] < a[j-1]) {
            int tmp;
            tmp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] = tmp;
            nswaps++;
        }
    }
    if (nswaps == 0) break;
 }
```

}

Comment: Because `a[j-1]` is undefined when `j` is zero. You should start with `j` at one (instead of zero).

Comment: OHHHHH thank you !! I'll try it out

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i still get a seg fault though?

Comment: post the new code

Comment: the code you post has `for(j = n-1`, answers say to use `for(j = 1`

Comment: @pm100 whoops typo i was trying other things, it still says seg fault

Comment: Why did you post updated code with no explanation?  If that is an answer to your own question, post it as an answer instead.

Comment: shouldnt that be `for ...  j < i`

Answer (score 2):

In the first iteration of the outer loop (when value of `i` is 0), the inner loop becomes an infinite loop, because value of `j` starts from 0 and keeps increasing. Eventually `j` becomes large enough for your program to access some unallocated memory, hence causing a segmentation fault.

Also, in the first iteration of the inner loop, value of `j` is 0, so `a[j - 1]` will try to access a memory location out of bound for your program.

Comment: thank you ! I tried making it j = 1 it still gives me a seg fault?

Answer (score 1):

`j > i` is false on the first iteration, so `if(nswaps == 0)` is true and the loops break, no sorting occurs.

---

Instead of iterating the outside loop `n` times, iterate `n-1` times.

No need to count swaps, a simply boolean is sufficient.

After the first inner loop iteration, the lowest element of the array is found and in place at the end.  The next inner loop only needs to iterate to next-last element, etc.

`size_t` is the Goldilocks type for array indexing, neither too narrow, nor too wide.  Better than using `int` for indexing.  Remember that is is an_unsigned type_.

No need to declare a variable until needed.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bubble_sort(int a[], size_t n) {
  while (n > 1) {
    bool swapped = false;
    for (size_t j = 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (a[j-1] < a[j]) {
        int tmp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[j - 1];
        a[j - 1] = tmp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
    if (!swapped) {
      break;
    }
    n--;
  }
}
```